# Does Java cache applets?

Tags: java, caching, applet

I have simple Applet example downloaded from Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/examplesIndex.html#HelloWorld
(applet_InvokingJavaScriptFromApplet)

When I made first launch, everything worked fine. **But when add some my own functions, recompile this code (with ant) and try to launch it again, my htmls cant call added functions?**

I cleared browsers cache, tried everything.

**My questions**

1. Does Java cache my applets ?
2. Is first answer Yes, so how to clear this cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  When it is open, type `x` then `c`.  One of the two clears the cache, the other clears the console text.  See the initial console text for which is which.

Comment: Maybe I can disable 'caching' option in JNLP file ? Also I've read, that people often add random param to http request(like applet?id=123432), but this doesnt help. Only thing that helps : renaming jar or jnlp file, but this seems to be bad solution but I'm ok with it.

Comment: *"Maybe I can disable 'caching' option in JNLP file ?"*  Short answer, no.  Long answer, nope.  Let's start with: it's not the decision of the person that wrote the JNLP, as to whether the **user** chooses to allow classes to be cached locally.  It is, after all, **their** machine.  You really shouldn't be testing applets in the browser until the last moments in any case.  Use the applet viewer.  It does not cache anything.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html#gcexdg)

> Application jars and resources are cached on the disk to avoid loading
>   them the next time they are needed.
>
> The default location of the cache depends on the operating system and
>   can be overidden in the Java Control Panel.
>
> Settings and controls for the cache are available in the General tab
>   of the Java Control Panel, in the Temporary Internet Files section.
>   Click Settings... to change the location and size of the cache. Click
>   View... to see what files are in the cache.
>
> You can clean the cache by running javaws -uninstall, or go to the
>   Java Control Panel's General tab, click View..., and delete files
>   manually. You can also use the Java Control Panel to uninstall
>   individual applications and extensions.